# JAVA- how to assign string value to string array dynamically

Tags: java

In my application i got string values dynamically. I want to assign these values to string array then print those values.But it shows an error(Null pointer exception)
EX:

```
String[] content = null;
for (int s = 0; s < lst.getLength(); s++) {
    String st1 = null;
    org.w3c.dom.Node nd = lst.item(s);
    if (nd.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        NamedNodeMap nnm = nd.getAttributes();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            st1 = ((org.w3c.dom.Node) nnm.item(i)).getNodeValue().toString();
        }
    }

    content[s] = st1;
    //HERE it shows null pointer Exception.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `for` loop `(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is telling it to do this loop once. That is a bit unusual. You could delete the loop and leave the contents inside and achieve the same results.

Answer (score 8):

This is because your string array is null. `String[] content=null;`

You declare your array as null and then try to assign values in it and that's why it is showing NPE.

You can try giving initial size to your string array or better to use `ArrayList<String>`.
ie:

```
String[] content = new String[10]; //--- You must know the size or array out of bound will be thrown.
```

Better if you use arrayList like

```
List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(); //-- no need worry about size.
```

For list use `add(value)` method to add new values in list and use `foreach` loop to print the content of list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList` or `Vector` for creating collection (or array) of strings in a dynamic fashion.

```
List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
Node node = (org.w3c.dom.Node) nnm.item(i)).getNodeValue();
if (null != node)
    contents.add(node.toString());
```

Outside the loop you can do as follows

```
for(String content : contents) {
     System.out.println(content) // since you wanted to print them out
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you're after because your example got munged.  However, your String array is null.  You need to initialize it, not just declare it.  Have you considered using an ArrayList instead?  Arrays in java are fixed length (unless they changed this since my university days).

ArrayList is a lot simpler to work with.

E.g.:

```
List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
   String toAdd;
   //do some stuff to get a value into toAdd
   content.add(toAdd)
}
```

There's also something weird with one of your for loops.

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
```

The above will only ever iterate once.  To clarify:

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
   System.out.println("hello");
}
```

is functionally identical to:

```
System.out.println("hello");
```

They both print out "hello" once, adn that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 content[s] = new String(st1);
```

Now it creates new instance for that particular array index.